# Robospice jars for non maven mode

Tags: android, robospice

I'm trying to make a build of a sample project (core-basic), without maven, just by picking the jars located in repository/dependencies/1.4.9/robospice and copying them to Android project libs folder.

The jars that I am copying are specifically these:

- commons-io-1.3.2
- commons-lang3-3.1
- robospice-1.4.9
- robospice-cache-1.4.9

However, Eclipse shows this error:

```
robospice-sample-core/libs/commons-lang3-3.1.jar' in project 'robospice-sample-core' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file
```

Moreover, I cannot access into the contents of the jars, WinRar says that they are corrupted or invalid.

So, what am I doing wrong? Can I really use those jar just by copying them to libs folder or do I have to do something more? Why does eclipse say that they can not be read?

(Thanks in advance. In spite of I know that maven setup for Robospice is strongly advisable, I'd like to know why this happens)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downloading jar by means of right click on its file name --> Save link returns corrupted jar files. Clicking on "Raw" in the file details, return the correct file.

Comment: You could also have cloned the repo branch, or picked the jars from maven central, or used the raw version on github as you mentionned.

Answer (score 1):

You must have made a mistake while downloading the files. They can be opened pretty easily with zipinfo on my mac. Download them again from the repo branch or pick the artifacts from maven central.